# The description about sorting in Model/View Qt document maybe wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qtreeview

In Qt document online Model/View Programming, it's said that If your model is sortable, i.e, if it reimplements the `QAbstractItemModel::sort()` function, both `QTableView` and `QTreeView` provide an API that allows you to sort your model data programmatically. In addition, you can enable interactive sorting (i.e. allowing the users to sort the data by clicking the view's headers), by connecting the `QHeaderView::sortIndicatorChanged() signal` to the `QTableView::sortByColumn() slot` or the `QTreeView::sortByColumn() slot`, respectively.
However, firstly the `QTableView::sortByColumn()` is not a slot, so one cannot connect a signal to it; secondly, the code of `QTableView::sortByColumn()` is something like

```
d->header->setSortIndicator(column, order);
//If sorting is not enabled, force to sort now.
if (!d->sortingEnabled)
    d->model->sort(column, order);
```

and `QHeaderView::setSortIndicator()` function emit `sortIndicatorChanged(logicalIndex, order)`. But if one uses function `setSortingEnabled(true)`, the signal `sortIndicatorChanged(logicalIndex, order)` can also be emitted automatically by the view header when click the header column of the view.

So maybe the right way is to make a slot to receive the signal `sortIndicatorChanged(logicalIndex, order)` and in the slot, call the override virtual function `sort()` of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the tree view by click a column.

1. Set the view can be sorted by click the "header".

   ```
   treeView_->setSortingEnabled(true);
   ```
2. Connect the header signal to a slot made by you.

   ```
   connect(headerView, SIGNAL(sortIndicatorChanged(int, Qt::SortOrder)),
       treeModel_, SLOT(sortByColumn(int, Qt::SortOrder)));
   ```
3. In the slot, call the `sort()` virtual function of the model. `sort()` virtual function is a virtual function of QAbstractItemModel, and one should override it.

   ```
   void TreeModel::sortByColumn(int column, Qt::SortOrder order)
   {
       sort(column, order);
   }
   ```
4. Override the `sort()` function as your model should do.
5. `emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex());` from a model to update the whole tree view.

Comment: Is this the correct use of ``dataChanged``?  Seems to me those indexes refers only to the root element (or something) or are even not defined?  On the other hand, looking at the source code for ``dataChanged`` in the View it more or less ignores the indexes.